# Getting error while running jar file java on adding <context:component-scan base-package="com.young.user" />

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [resources/application-context.xml]
```

please help why i am getting this error

Comment: do you have spring context jar in your classpath?

Comment: yes ,i have spring context jar in my classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue might be `spring-context.jar` is missing from your `classpath`. Try adding spring-context dependency to your `pom.xml`, or if not using `maven` download the jar and add to your lib folder.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the spring jars are not included in your classpath. Add it to the classpath and it should work.